# Using Watir to detect that an element is hidden by overflow

Tags: overflow, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to use Watir to tell whether or not an element is hidden using the overflow: hidden css property.  The only way that I have thought to do this would be to figure out where the containing div is and see whether the contained element falls within it or not.  Methods like visible? and present? return true even when the contained element is completely hidden.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to use `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`. This should tell you what the top element is at a specific coordinate. If your element is hidden due to the overflow, it will return a different element.

The following seems to work for the examples on w3schools.com:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

class Watir::Element
    def hidden_by_overflow?()
        assert_exists
        assert_enabled

        # Add one to the coordinates because, otherwise, if there is no border       
        # between this element and another element, we might get the element right   
        # above or to the left of this one                                           
        top_left_x = @element.location.x + 1
        top_left_y = @element.location.y + 1
        top_test = browser.execute_script("return document.elementFromPoint(#{top_left_x}, #{top_left_y})")

        return top_test != self
    end
end

begin
    b.goto('http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_overflow&preval=hidden')
    b.div(:id, 'demoDIV').ps.each{ |x| puts x.hidden_by_overflow? }
    #=> The first 9 paragraphs of the 16 paragraphs return true.
ensure
    b.close
end
```

Note:

- I tested this in Firefox. Not sure if it will be browser compatible.
- The check is only checking that the top left corner of your element is not hidden. Elements that are partially outside the containing div would still return true. I tried making a check for the bottom corner using @element.size.height, but webdriver started scrolling the results in the containing div.

Comment: document.elementFromPoint isn't completely browser compatible as explained in http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/, but since no one should be scrolling the page in a watir test, this should work.  I also had to make some edits (adding +1 to the x and y) to avoid a case where two elements were right next to one another and the elementFromPoint would return the one above. Thanks!

Comment: Also, this method will NOT work if there is another element that is directly on top of the current element (ie, if you have a div inside a div with no border or padding or anything, then this method will get the innermost div).  To be safe, this method should only be used for innermost elements.